# Can multiple branches be identical in MWI?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

As I understand it, Many Worlds Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics states that all possibilities are realized.

That part is easy enough to understand. But my question is: Does there exist multiple branches that are 100% identical? Or is every branch different from one another in some way?

For example, are there multiple branches in which the events leading up to right now are exactly the same? Or is there only 1 branch per possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Everettian worlds branch out at choices with certain weights based on Born's rule. No two branches will therefore have identical histories. It is however possible for two branches to recohere i.e their states become identical again at some point after branching. In this case the worlds are said to merge. Whether you believe they physically merge (if you subscribe to the MWI), or this is simply terminology, is a metaphysical question I don't think is answerable. Since they are identical it doesn't matter if you treat them as having recombined or as still seperate but identical.

Comment: wait it sounds like you at first said that branches are never identical, and then later you said branches can be identical ...

Comment: In response to the part of your question 'are there multiple branches in which the events leading up to right now are exactly the same?' The answer is no, the ordering of events will always be different. You can't have two branches that, at the point immediately after branching are identical. You can however have two non-identical branches that end up in the same configuration (so become identical). When this happens they are said to merge.

Comment: What is the equation of motion for a branch?

Comment: I could have sworn that i heard that for example there could be multiple worlds that are identical to ours that may or may not branch out and become different

Comment: Sure, and that doesn't contradict my answer. In MWI there is one universal wave function; it describes the entire universe. So picture the entire universe in superposition. When a quantum measurement happens the one world, which is in a superposition, decoheres into all possibilities. If I have a particle that's in a superposition of spin up and spin down, then it's not correct to say there are two parallel worlds where each option happens sometime later (since the worlds can't communicate). There is one world, and when measurement happens it splits into two to reflect the two possibilities.

Comment: On the metaphysical side this leads to interesting ideas, like quantum immortality, and there's quite a sad story regarding Hugh Everett's daughter in this regard you might be interested in looking up (she commited suicide in order to be with her dad). It's not really physics though; whether it's right or wrong, you can't do anything with this information which is unfalsifiable. MWI leads to some useful visualisations within quantum information though, so that's where it shows its use.